# Изменение фона при скролле

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, анимация

Хочу реализовать следующее - при достижении определенной секции на сайте, например "`<div id="client"></div>`", менялся фон на сайте.
Пока делаю простенький пример с 2-мя секциями

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  now = 1;

  function func(selector, number_photo) {

    var target = $(selector);
    var targetPos = target.offset().top;
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollToElem = targetPos - winHeight;

    $(window).scroll(function() {

      var winScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

      if (winScrollTop > scrollToElem + scrollToElem * 2) {

        if (!(now == number_photo)) {
          $('body').removeClass('back' + now);
          $('body').addClass('back' + number_photo);
          now = number_photo;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    func('#main', 1);
    func('#clients', 2);
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("/Anime/images/top-slider/1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transition: background 2s linear;
}

.back1 {
  background-image: url("/Anime/images/top-slider/1.jpg");
}

.back2 {
  background-image: url("/Anime/images/top-slider/2.jpg");
}

#main {
  height: 900px;
}

#clients {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  MAIN
</div>

<div id="client">
  CLIENT
</div>
```

Проблема заключается в следующем, пока не закончится переход на 2-ю картинку, то при скролле, заново начинается переход на эту же 2-ю картинку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере добавляется каждый раз новый обработчик на событие scroll, а еще вы внутри самого обработчика события scroll через функцию добавляете новые обработчики события scroll...

Я просто переписал начисто, надеюсь комментариев достаточно. Решение без jQuery, на HTML5, если нужна поддержка старых браузеров - будет несложно поменять некоторые конструкции на jQuery, я же этого делать не стал, так как в вопросе не требовалось.

```js
(function () {
  // Массив элементов блоков ([0]) и классов ([1]), которые они применяют к body
  var blocks = [
    [ document.querySelector("#id-1"), "deep-purple" ],
    [ document.querySelector("#id-2"), "green" ],
    [ document.querySelector("#id-3"), "deep-orange" ],
  ];

  // Последний выбранный блок - используется для того, чтобы лишний раз не менять классы, если блок не сменился при прокрутке
  var lastBlock = null;

  // Функция, определяющая, какой блок сейчас "виден"
  // Выбирает блок, средина которого находится ближе всего к средине экрана
  function updateBodyBackground() {
    // Ищем блок, который сейчас находится ближе всего к центру экрана
    var screenCenterHeight = document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight / 2;
    var nearestBlock = null;
    var nearestDistance;
    blocks.forEach(function(block) {
      var blockCenterHeight = block[0].offsetTop + block[0].offsetHeight / 2;
      var distance = Math.abs(blockCenterHeight - screenCenterHeight);
      if (nearestBlock == null || distance < nearestDistance) {
        nearestDistance = distance;
        nearestBlock = block;
      }
    });

    if (nearestBlock != lastBlock) {
      // Если это не тот же блок, что был раньше, действуем
      lastBlock = nearestBlock;

      // Убираем старые классы всех блоков
      blocks.forEach(function(block) {
        document.body.classList.remove(block[1]);
      });

      // Добавляем текущий
      document.body.classList.add(nearestBlock[1]);
    }
  }

  // Вызываем во время прокрутки страницы
  document.addEventListener('scroll', updateBodyBackground);

  // Вызываем сразу при загрузке стрианицы
  updateBodyBackground();

  // ... можно динамически добавлять / убирать блоки, изменяя элементы массива blocks и вызывая после этого updateBodyBackground()
})();
```

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body.deep-purple {
  background-color:#512DA8;
}
body.green {
  background-color:#388E3C;
}
body.deep-orange {
  background-color:#E64A19;
}

.block {
  height:1000px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:72px;
  line-height:1000px;
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div id="id-1" class="block">1</div>
  <div id="id-2" class="block">2</div>
  <div id="id-3" class="block">3</div>
 </body>
</html>
```